# Tiling an array in place with numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I have an image stored in RGBA format as a 3d numpy array in python, i.e.

`image = np.zeros((500, 500, 4), dtype=np.int16)`

would be a transparent, black 500x500 square.

I would like to be able to quickly fill the image with a uniform color. For instance `fill_img(some_instance_with_img, (255, 0, 0, 255))` would fill the image stored in `some_instance_with_img` with opaque red. The following code does the trick, assuming `self` is an instance that contains an image stored as `image`:

```
def fill_img(self, color):
    color = np.array(color)
    shape = self.image.shape
    self.image = np.tile(color, (shape[0] * shape[1])).reshape(shape)
```

However, it creates a brand new array and simply reassigns self.image to this new array. What I would like to do is avoid this intermediate array. If `np.tile` had an `out` argument, it would look like:

```
def fill_img(self, color):
    color = np.array(color)
    shape = self.image.shape
    np.tile(color, (shape[0] * shape[1]), out=self.image)
    self.image.reshape(shape)
```

but `np.tile` does not support an `out` parameter. It feels like I am just missing something, although it is possible that this behavior doesn't exist. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `image[:,:,:] = [255, 0, 0, 255]`  (I'd make this an answer, but I suspect this question is a duplicate.)

Comment: Wow! That is way simpler than I thought. Thank you.

Comment: I was unable to find anything when searching which is why I did not think it was a duplicate, but I did not to think to search for broadcasting/indexing, because I didn't think that's how that worked. Happy to delete the question if it's unhelpful though.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest things can be difficult to search for.  If someone finds a dup, they can mark it as a dup.  On the other hand, if someone else wants to get some points by creating a longer tutorial-like answer that incorporates my comment and explains how `:` is handled in an assignment, that would be great!

Comment: But seriously, I would like to make a tile inplace

Comment: Can you give an example of what you’d like to do @Madlozoz?

Comment: @Thomas in pygame, I want to tile a pattern array(200,200,3) into a screen array(900,900,3). I know I should blit, but just for fun I'd like to use numpy